In Excel, is there a way to get the column and row names where a value exists?
The values I have are minimum and maximum from a range that spans years of sales. The columns represent the years, and these are not all just numbers, they have variances and other things, so just getting the years was a bit of a challenge on itself.
After I got the minimum sales and maximum sales from across twenty-two years, I thought I could simply use xlookup to find the year and another xlookup to find the day, but it didn't work because the range is not just one row or column, but a couple hundred.
To give an example:



Day\Year
2024
2023
2022
2021
2020




1
9900
8600.
2900.
7300.
9000


2
5340
2100
99
890
7777



The min is 99, so I want to find a way to write the column it belongs to (2022) and the day (2).
I'll appreciate any help.
I tried xlookup and index/match, but because the range I am covering to find the value spans multiple rows and columns, I get #value errors.
ChatGPT 4o didn't figure out this, even after I shared my workbook, it gave me index and matches for one year, instead of the full 22 years.

index with match, lots of examples on here.

=TEXTJOIN("; ",,REPT("Year "&B1:E1&", Day "&A2:A3,B2:E3=MIN(B2:E3)))
This works if there's more than one of the same min value as well.
It may require entering with ctrl+shift+enter

Not an alternate solution, just a suggestion and explanation of P.b.'s clever use of REPT:


If number_times is 0 (zero), REPT returns "" (empty text).



You may want to define a name for the data area (and perhaps the headers) for ease of use.
With data defined, we can refer to the years by OFFSET(data,-1,0,1) and days similarly.


You may want to take a look at this also: Named Ranges in Excel | Exceljet

For fun, defining a resuable function in Name Manager:
_list_col_row_for_value: List column and row headers for a given value within the given range.
=LAMBDA(data, lookup_value, result_header,  
LET(  
header_start, OFFSET(data,-1,-1,1,1),  
_col, LAMBDA(c, OFFSET(header_start,, COLUMN(c) - COLUMN(header_start))),  
_row, LAMBDA(c, OFFSET(header_start, ROW(c) - ROW(header_start),0)),  
REDUCE(result_header, data,  
LAMBDA(acc, cur,
IF(cur = lookup_value, VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(_col(cur), _row(cur))), acc)  ))))


